# Obtener mes de una fecha en react (mapeando un array)

Tags: reactjs

Estoy bajando un json desde axios en react, y necesito obtener el mes de todas las fechas que baje, sin embargo sale `"valor.fecha.getMonth is not a function"`.
Hay alguna forma de alojar la fecha en una variable (algo complicado, ya que se está iterando)?

```
<tbody>
                    {dailyList.map((valor, key) => (
                        <tr key={key}>
                            <td>
                                <span>{valor.fecha}</span>
                            </td>
                                <span>{valor.cant}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>{valor.tiempo}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>{(60/valor.tiempo)}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>${(1/(60/valor.tiempo)).toFixed(1)}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>${(1/(60/valor.tiempo)).toFixed(2)*valor.cant}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>{(valor.fecha).getMonth()}</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar tu JSON que estás mapeando?

Comment: ¿Por qué estás accediendo a la función así `(valor.fecha).getMonth()`? ¿No debería ser así `valor.fecha.getMonth()`? No entiendo el propósito de esos paréntesis.

Comment: @Daniel el json que obtengo es éste[{"id":2,"fecha":"2022-07-01T00:00:00","maquina":"H2","pieza":"Cortical","cant":12,"tiempo":4},{"id":4,"fecha":"2022-07-02T00:00:00","maquina":"H1","pieza":"05","cant":14,"tiempo":4}]

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu JSON que compartes puedes usar [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
var date =new Date("2022-07-02T00:00:00");
    
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}));
```

que te daria como resultado

```
07/02/2022
```

y solo usando localestring

```
 var date =new Date("2022-07-02T00:00:00");

    
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

tendrias como resultado

```
7/2/2022, 12:00:00 AM
```

resolviendo tu error usando tolocalestring

```
new Date(valor.fecha).toLocaleString()
```